# Replace string using MAP and LAMBDA in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, lambda

I have a dataframe column called 'event' in a dataframe called 'calendar'. Obviously it contains event names and I want to replace those names by a single string. To do so, I use a few filters based on the content of the event names.

For instance, I want to replace all the names containing 'BoE','BoC','Fed', 'ECB' ,'RBA' or 'RBNZ' and also contain the word 'Speak' by simply 'Speak'.

To achieve that, I made this code:

```
banks=['BoE','BoC','Fed', 'ECB' ,'RBA','RBNZ']
calendar['event'] = list(map(lambda x : 'Speak' if any(bancs) and 'Speak' in x else x, calendar['event']))
```

Most of times it works fine, but I usally get the error: `'DataFrame' object is not callable'`. I guess there's something wrong in the syntax so I'll be thankfull with any correction or any alternative code that can be useful

Comment: so, this is a `pandas` question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current code seems to have both typos and logical errors (e.g. your use of `any`).
Try this -

```
banks=['BoE','BoC','Fed', 'ECB' ,'RBA','RBNZ']
calendar['event'] = list(map(lambda x : 'Speak' if (any([b in x for b in banks]) and 'Speak' in x) else x, calendar['event']))
```

Testing on a simple example:

```
calendar = pd.DataFrame(columns=['event'])
calendar['event'] = ['Speak BoC', 'BoE', 'Speak Q', 'RBNZSpeak']  # Only 1st and 3rd should be replaced by "Speak"
banks=['BoE','BoC','Fed', 'ECB' ,'RBA','RBNZ']
calendar['event'] = list(map(lambda x : 'Speak' if (any([b in x for b in banks]) and 'Speak' in x) else x, calendar['event']))
print(calendar.event)
# 0      Speak
# 1        BoE
# 2    Speak Q
# 3      Speak
```

But none of your typos/mistakes seem to relate to your error, so there might be problems elsewhere in your code.
You should post an error-producing example if the answers here don't address your problem.

Comment: Thank you! I replaced the code but the error persists... and I think I started realizing what is the problem... but I can't understand why is it happening:  This code line (now yours) is inside a function that I'm calling within a loop and first iteration works, but for some reason, on further iterations I got the same error:  'DataFrame' object is not callable'

Comment: You're probably overiding a variable or something. Please share enough context of your code (e.g. the loop, or a MCVE in general) if you want help with this.

Comment: Thank you! You're right, there already was a variable in globals called "any" declared during the outside loop. However I've implemented your corrected syntax